# Android studio startup error

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been having an issue with android studio for the past two weeks, it started happening out of the blue, everything was working juts fine until one day it just wouldn't start, it's display an error for me, I tried doing the following since then:

- Reinstall the same version on android studio (which is the latest)
- Install different versions of android studio
- Restore my computer to a previous date in which everything was working fine

Needless to say that all of the above hasn't worked
Would anyone know how to solve this problem ?
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: What happens when you click on "Re-download dependencies" ?

Comment: I just get the same message again

Comment: Confirm Android studio is up-to-date,confirm android -sdk is up-to-date,,if it asks for downloading dependencies..download..then if it not solve the problem ....then close and re-open the project...do a clean and build

Comment: I faced this problem months ago and solved it too but forgot what I did. I guess I deleted SDK folder completely and re-ran the download process of SDK components. Give it a try, may work but with no guarantee. Good Luck!!!!

Comment: @King I have the latest versions of android studio and android sdk, I tried doing as you said but when I rebuild or clean the project I get the following error (which is the error I've been getting for a while):

Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.
Cause:
com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.weakValues()Lcom/google/common/collect/MapMaker;

Comment: @AawazGyawali thanks, I've alrady tried this option, I'll try it again, and see what it does.

Comment: @HusaynHakeem - Can you upgrade google collection library and give a clean and build ? The problem as something to do with MapleMaker.WeakValues() which is for Auto GC.

Comment: I downloaded the library and made sure the right classes I need are in it, but I didn't find the google-collection package neither in the android studio folder or in the sdk folder, do you know where it is ?

Answer (score -1):

After failing to find a solution, I just downloaded Intellij IDEA, it's great and has the same interface as android studio, so I'd advise anyone having issues with android studio to use it